# data fitting by Integration with variable limit with a unknown parameter in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, numerical-integration

I want to fit experimental data with equation:

```
y = C(1) * 74.826 * (x/T(1))^3 * integration (t^4*exp(t)/(exp(t)-1)^2), 0, T(1)/x) + 
C(2) * 24.942 * (T(2)/x)^2  * exp(T(2)/x)/(exp(T(2)/x)-1)^2 +  C(3) * 24.942 * 
(T(3)/x)^2 * *exp(T(3)/x)/(exp(T(3)/x)-1)^2
```

with six unknown parameters: `C(1), T(1), C(2), T(2), C(3), T(3)`.

How to write the program for this? Please help.
I have data in `x` and `y`. want to find these 6 unknowns.
Thank you.

Comment: do you know anything about C(1)...T(3), are they bounded by some limits, or can be anything?

Comment: also what are the sizes of x,y ?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB Curve fitting toolbox is your fried!

```
F = fit(xdata, ydata, 'YourEquation');

plot(F, xdata, ydata);
```